# In python im getting error converting unix timestamp to date and time. Os Error #22

Tags: python

Guys Im taking this Unix timestamp and converting it to date time. I have tried absolutly everything and cant figure out why im getting this error. Can someone please help me figure this out please.

1605195918507251700

Using this function

```
def ts_to_datetime(ts) -> str:
    return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts / 1000.0).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
```

Comment: `1605195918507251700` is not a unix timestamp.  Where did you get this value from?

Comment: From the api im using it says the time stamp is a msec unix timestamp

Comment: What API are you using?  Does it offer another value that's a "proper" unix timestamp (in seconds)?

Comment: polygon api and it does not how can I convert this time stamp which is msec unix timestamp to seconds unix timestamp

Comment: I think the value you have is actually in μs, (microseconds) not ms (milliseconds).

Comment: how could I convert it

Comment: According to epochconverter.com it's a timestamp is in nanoseconds. So `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts / 1000000000).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')` gives `'2020-11-12 10:45'`

Comment: I think you'd just need to divide it by `1000000` instead of `1000`.  Try `ts // 1000000`.

Comment: ok thank you I will try it

Comment: @JohnnyMopp You're right.  It's actually `1000000000` (not `1000000`) like I thought.  I was a bit off in my amount of decimal places...

Comment: It works guys thanks